# Concurrency implications of EAFP/LBYL

Tags: python, multithreading

When writing concurrent/multithreaded code in Python, is it especially important to follow the "Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission" (EAFP) idiom, rather than "Look Before You Leap" (LBYL)?  Python's exceptionally dynamic nature means that almost anything (e.g., attribute removal) can happen between looking and leaping---if so, what's the point?  For example, consider

```
# LBYL
if hasattr(foo, 'bar'):
    baz = foo.bar
```

versus

```
# EAFP
try:
    baz = foo.bar
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

In the LBYL example, the `bar` attribute could disappear from `foo` before the actual call to `foo.bar` is made, so do you gain anything from the check?  If there's a risk the attribute might disappear, you need locks and/or try/except clauses anyway.

One possible argument here is that this example makes the extremely pessimistic assumption that "antagonistic code" is running that could yank the rug from under you at any moment.  In most use cases, this is highly unlikely.

Comment: Just wanted to put in a plug that you don't commonly add/delete attributes from objects just because you can. It's one of those "when it's practical, but know the downsides" kinds of decisions. As we see from your cool question, it can be particularly confusing if combined with concurrency concerns.

Comment: absolutely agree---and when doing so, people need to be heads up regarding the implications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thoughts are correct.  Some additional points:

If the attribute exists most of the time, try:except: might be much faster than
the LBYL idiom.

If you don't like the try: except: syntax, you can also write:

```
item = getattr(foo, 'bar', None)
if item is None:
    ....
else:
    ....
```

Comment: +1: The performance has been beaten to death -- the try/except is generally faster.  And more reliable.  And the assumption about other threads is not "extremely pessimistic" -- it's essential to success.

Comment: I don't know if getattr is guaranteed to be atomic in CPython. The GIL might make it so, but it's probably not atomic in Jython or IronPython.

Certainly the two-step LBYL hasattr above cannot be atomic.

Comment: good point, george.  my guess is that on the inside, we've got an EAFP try-catch block that returns None if anything goes wrong